# SwitchCompatNotify is not getting string from strings.xml resource in text property

Tags: android

I'm trying to do the following:

```
<com.ophiropt.meissa.view.SwitchCompatNotify
                    android:id="@+id/trigger_switch_channel_b"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:text="@{@string/channel+ @string/b}"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

but I don't see any text near the switch if I write a "hard-coded" text like:

```
android:text="channel a"
```

I see the text near the switch without any problem, 
is this a bug of Android?
how can I get it to work?
(I can't put there a hard-coded word because I need it to be translated to 5 languages )

any idea?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the problem wasn't with the `SwitchCompatNotify` by the end,
the problem was with the inflating of the dialog that contained it.
we can have a text like this: `android:text="@{@string/channel+ @string/b}"`
only if the dialod is using data binding,
and in this case the inflate of the dialog was a regular one without using data binding(`DataBindingUtil.inflate`), therefore it didn't work.